# Difference between typeof === and typeof ==

Tags: javascript

What is the difference in using `typeof ===` or `typeof ==` or is same thing?, since both return the same value.

```js
function main() {
  var number = 10;

  console.log(typeof number == 'number'); // true
  console.log(typeof number === 'number'); // true
}
main();
```

Comment: `typeof array` returns a string, so there's little practical difference.

Comment: What does the function and the variable number have to do with the question?  I.e. remove it if not relevant.  You do need to define array.

Comment: @AllanWind typo

Comment: Your expression is evaluated like this `(typeof number) === 'number'` and `typeof number` in your case is `number` which is equal to `'number'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typeof` operator always returns a string. The `===` compares both the value and the type whereas `==` operator only compares the value.

This means both the `==` and `===` comparators will always act the same when you have `typeof` and a string on two sides of them.

Comment: Both operators check the type; `==` checks it on multiple occasions while performing type coercion, `===` only compares the type once. You cannot compare “only the values” if they are of different types. See the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).

Comment: Look at the context of the question. The type is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer using the [strict equality comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) `===` as is a subset of the `==`.  The latter does type conversations like null and undefined being equal which can be surprising.

Answer (score -2):

=== makes a strict comparison and only returns true if the compared elements have the same value and type

== compares only in terms of values, not type of data